# Proper Setup of Active Record Associations for a Doctor-Patient Survey Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am having some trouble building my Active Record Associations for a Doctor -> Patient relationship.

Doctors can create Assessments for their patients. But before they create an Assessment, they must choose a Template (for the type of injury). A Template has_many :questions, and a Question has_many :answers.

**So the models are: User, Patient, Assessment, Template, Question, Answer.**

The User --> Patient relationship is pretty straight forward, but I'm having trouble with the the template, assessment, questions, and answers. I'm pretty confused about the 'has_many :through'. I'd like to be able to call Template.questions to get the list of questions for given template, but *also* be able to call Assessment.questions (instead of Assessment.template.questions).

Then I can filter through the Assessment.questions to get the answers.

Here are my current Model associations. The current setup isn't allowing me to call Assessment.questions (which I thought would be taken care of by the has_many :questions, :through=> :templates).

What do I need to change in order to call Assessment.questions ? Also accepting any other feedback on the architecture.

thanks

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patients
  has_many :assessments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :assessments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Assessment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :template
  belongs_to :patient
  has_many :questions, :through=> :templates
  has_many :answers, :through=> :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end

class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :assessment
    has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Comment: You have belongs_to :assessment on template and belongs_to :template on assessment.  That's a problem.

Comment: Patients have many users through assessments and Users have many patients through assessments sounds about right.  You haven't coherently explained the goals or the domain for the project to give me a good understanding of how the models should be associated to one another.

Comment: Thanks @Noah. It's a simple tool for Doctors to manage their patient list and take assessments. I have a view to show all the patients, and a patient can have multiple assessments which all show on their profile. Although a patient can still exist without an assessment

Comment: Anyway, even your first point on the double belongs_to fixed my problem. Now I can call Assessment.questions, thanks!

Comment: What's the point of changing Patients and Users to has_many :through vs the current setup?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would do it this way.  I may not be fully understanding your goal, but I think I do:

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assessments
    has_many :patients, :through => :assessments
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assessments
    has_many :doctors, :through => :assessments
end

class Assessment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :templates
    belongs_to :patient
    belongs_to :doctor
end

class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions
    belongs_to :assessment
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers
    belongs_to :template
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
end
```

Comment: How would I then render a list of a given patient's assessments? I originally wanted to call @patient.assessments to see a history

Comment: After my edit, you can do Patient.first.assessments.

Comment: My two concerns: #1 I can't call Assessment.questions to get a direct list of questions associated with that assessment and #2 Ideally I would like to call Assessment.questions.first.answer to get the associated answer for that question *for the associated assessment*

Comment: To be clear, I have a "Questions" table with a list of Questions that I am re-using for different templates. So it's not like a new question ID is getting created every time there's a new assessment. It's the same question_id, but on a different assessment_id